# How much information can we extract about such a group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be a group with the property : Given any positive integers $m, n$ and $r$ there exists elements $g, h\in G$ such that $|g|=m, |h|=n$ and $|gh|=r$

Where $|g|$ is the order of the group $\langle g\rangle$

Is it hopeless to classify all groups upto isomorphism having the said property or such classification have already done?

How much information can we extract about such a group?

Few elementary known properties

1. $G$ can't be finite.
2. $G$ can't be cyclic.
3. $G$ has to be a non abelian group.

The difficulty is that I can't use fundamental theorem to classify such infinite non abelian group.

Comment: What is an example of such a group?

Comment: Tedious objection: if one of $m,n,r$ is $1$ then the other two have to be equal. Best just to assume $m,n,r>1$.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda For a first example: Enumerate all triangle groups, then take their free product. You can then get a finitely presented example by embedding this group into a finitely presented group via Higman's embedding theorem.

Comment: Another example is the group of automorphisms of the integers generated by the transposition $(0,1)$ and the map $n\mapsto n+1$. This contains all the finite symmetric groups; now use a theorem of GA Miller.

Comment: Note that such a group could still be locally finite, since for every triple $(m, n, r)$ there's a finite group with such $g$ and $h$, which follows either from residual finiteness or triangle groups or can be shown directly for $\operatorname{PSL}_2 \mathbb{F}_q$ (Theorem 1.64 in https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf)

Comment: Of course there's no classification of such groups since it would imply a classification of all overgroups of some given group.

Comment: @GilesGardam What  about  a possible  "simple" example: a simple  group  with the  property under  discussion?The  example  you mentioned is  a  direct product of all possible finite  group mentioned in theorem 1.64(for  all  m,n, r) but it is  not a  simple  group. So  is there a  simple example  and then classification of  all  simple example  would be  the  next question

Comment: what  about if we replace  arbitrary $r$  with  $r=lcm (m,n)$? namely  for every  $m,n$ there  are elements $g,h$  with $|g|=m,\quad |h|=n,\quad  |gh|=\frac{mn}{gcd(m,n)}$?